# HTML5 multiple images selection limit and edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a multiple image previewer where the limit is 5 selections, and if I want to change one of my selections, I click the x on that image and re-select a new image

My code right now shows an alert but still allows the selection afterwards. Please help!

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3D6pd/)

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
<br><output id="list"></output>
```

script:

```
$(function() {
$("input#files[type='file']").change(function(){
        var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>6){
         alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
         return false;
        }
    });  
});

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; 
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) { continue;   }
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: Indeed, using the `event.stopPropagation()` is the way to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: DRAT. Deleted my comment on accident.  LOL  What I said was modify your `function()` to be `function(event)` and then right before `return false` add `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: i added 'event' inside the () for function, and added event.stopPropagation(); like you said. I still have the same problem. After the alert I see all the selections showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this working  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3D6pd/1/

Just put

```
 var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>6){
         alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
         return false;
        }
```

this code inside the handleFileSelect function and use `evt.stopPropagation();`

Comment: the link you posted works for the most part. If i select 4 pictures then try to select 7 pictures i will stop it. But if I select 4 pictures, then go and select 1, then another, then another, i can keep going and overriding the limit again.

Comment: U can take a global count variable and increment it to the length of files every time when u select files and check for count less than 7 in the condition before accepting the image file, else wait for tomorrow i will certainly help you.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that so I will wait for your help. Here is an updated version http://jsfiddle.net/3D6pd/2/ (I added the x's for image deselection)

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/3D6pd/5/ . Let me know if you have any other doubt.

Comment: Nice! It's not letting more than 5 like I wanted which is great! Only question is, when I attempt to select 8 pictures, even though it doesn't let the preview of the 8, it still says "8 selected", does that mean on submit it will still upload 8? is there a way to clear that field from saying how many selected if it didn't allow the preview?

Comment: Yes u can take length of files plus the global count variable and if this is greater than 5 then hide the text showing files length

Comment: is there a way to make it reset the field rather than hide the amount select (if more than 5 are selected)? because on submission, the hidden stuff will still go through right

Comment: Then simply display count as text in that field.

Comment: I don't get it.. I don't care what visually is displayed, I care about what happens behind the scenes on submit. If I select 8 images which this code alerts saying I can't do that, are the 8 images going to be still uploaded if I click submit or will it tell me there is no selection made?

Comment: Why dont you upload only those images which are displayed on the page

Comment: How do I only pass these ones to the submission? Or is it already doing that?

Answer (score 1):

this is updated fiddle try  http://jsfiddle.net/3D6pd/6/

I have added a form and a submit button here,

```
 $("#sub").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        alert("files uploaded="+ $("input#files[type='file']").get(0).files.length);

    });
    var count=0;
```

hope this helps

Comment: the alert on submit shows the amount that is selected (or attempted to select). If I select 7 images, it alerts I can only upload 5 and doesn't show any previews which is good, but when I click submit it says 7 images are uploaded. Is there a way to empty out the input field if it was over the limit for that selection attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I have added this to your fiddle

```
$(function() {
    var array=[];
    $("#sub").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $("input#files[type='file']").get(0).files=array;

        alert("files uploaded="+ $("input#files[type='file']").get(0).files.length);

    });
    var count=0;
    // Preview should only have up to 5 images
    // onclick x, preview of that image should be deselected and removed from the preview screen

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
        count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>6 || count>5){
             alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
             count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
             evt.preventDefault();
             evt.stopPropagation();
             return false;
        }
         var files = evt.target.files; 
         array = array.concat(files);

        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) { continue;   }
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview">x</span>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);  



});
```

Comment: this does the same as your above answer. I still get an alert "7 images uploaded" even though it wasn't in the preview. In other words, I want to alert only what the preview is showing. If it is not in the preview, it shouldn't be alerted